# How to transfer draft envelope via REST or SOAP

Tags: docusignapi

I have a system account under which I create a draft envelope. Next, I need to transfer it to another employee.

The envelope is successfully created via [REST (C# nuget)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/). Next, I connect via SOAP (dsapi.asmx) and try to transfer using the [TransferEnvelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/reference/post-processing-group/transferenvelope/) method.

- AccountID - Specified the id of the current system account and the Id of the employee to whom I want to transfer
- UserID - 'API username' to whom I want to transfer

I get the error:
**The specified envelope is not in a terminal state and cannot be transferred** (**ENVELOPE_CANNOT_TRANSFER_INVALID_STATE**, code **134**)

Found a similar post but no solution:
https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W0000726aVz/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-ownership-of-draft-envelopes-via-the-soap-api

I need to prepare a draft envelope and give it to an employee who will finish creating it and send it for approval.

Answer (score 0):

Draft envelopes cannot be transferred through the API.

Comment: Ok, why then can I do [this](https://ibb.co/M2pWmnf)?

Comment: Great question. My understanding is that you shouldn't be able to.